# How to show code from a script in a publish?

Tags: matlab

I want to publish my assignment with matlab.

At the start of the program, I want to print the code of my scripts to show the teacher what my functions do.

How can I do this?

So far the best way I do this is by making a dummy call at the start without ending the function call with ";"

However I'd really like to just print the code at the start.

Comment: Is there not an ["Include Code"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/specifying-output-preferences-for-publishing.html#bthge9l) option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the type command:

```
type fileName.m
```

This will print the code, similarly to creating a variable and not using a semicolon to see the value of that variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools in MATLAB for publishing code. You could conceivably even write a report in MATLAB code and publish that! Take a look at [publishing MATLAB code](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/publishing-matlab-code.html) and the documentation of the function [`publish`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/publish.html)

If you are interested to print particular lines from a `.m` file, look into [`dbtype`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbtype.html).

Illustration from Mathworks site linked above. This:
[image]

becomes this:
[image]

Comment: thanks for your time!! However the other answer is simpler and enough for my needs

Comment: @Cher no problem. I hope it may be useful later or to someone else.